# Couldn't print to this printer: Failed to load image. mike42/Escpos-php

Tags: php, pos, escpos

hello can anyone help me with this error
**Couldn't print to this printer: Failed to load image.**

my code

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Mike42\Escpos\Printer;
use Mike42\Escpos\EscposImage;
use Mike42\Escpos\ImagickEscposImage;
use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\WindowsPrintConnector;
use Mike42\Escpos\GdEscposImage;

try {
    $connector = new WindowsPrintConnector("XP-80");
    $img = EscposImage::load("logo.png", false);
    $printer = new Printer($connector);
    //$printer -> selectPrintMode();
    $printer -> setJustification(Printer::JUSTIFY_CENTER);
    $printer -> graphics($img);
    $printer -> text("Hello World!\n");
    $printer -> cut();
    
    /* Close printer */
    $printer -> close();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Couldn't print to this printer: " . $e -> getMessage() . "\n";
}
```

Comment: You probably need to specify the full path to your logo.png file when you pass the filename parameter to the `load()` method. Maybe something like `EscposImage::load(__DIR__ . '/images/logo.png')` or whatever it might be.

Comment: `$img = EscposImage::load(__DIR__ .'/logo.png', false);`

Comment: the same error I have 3 days trying to fix this

Comment: Is that where the file is? Is it a valid PNG file? What does `var_dump($img)` show?

Comment: object(Mike42\Escpos\GdEscposImage)#2 (7) { ["imgHeight":protected]=> int(0) ["imgWidth":protected]=> int(0) ["imgData":"Mike42\Escpos\EscposImage":private]=> NULL ["imgColumnData":"Mike42\Escpos\EscposImage":private]=> array(0) { } ["imgRasterData":"Mike42\Escpos\EscposImage":private]=> NULL ["filename":"Mike42\Escpos\EscposImage":private]=> string(32) "C:\xampp\htdocs\options\logo.png" ["allowOptimisations":"Mike42\Escpos\EscposImage":private]=> bool(false) } Couldn't print to this printer: Failed to load image.

Answer (score 0):

**solved ImagickEscposImage is not installed now it's working
thanks Alex**